# how can i do "removeEmptyTag:False" in django-ckeditor in settings.py

Tags: python, django, django-ckeditor

> source

```
<div class="icon-lg text-white m-b15"><i class="flaticon-fuel-station"></i></div>
```

> output

```
<div class="icon-lg text-white m-b15">&nbsp;</div>
```

> django-ckeditor automatic remove  tag :{

Answer (score 0):

There is this [issue on github](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/issues/552), it is actually not a bug, it is a feature.

To disable this *feature* add this to your config:

> `'allowedContent': True, 'extraAllowedContent': '*(*)',`

Optional - [customizing CKEditor editor](https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#optional-customizing-ckeditor-editor)

Comment: 'removePlugins': 'stylesheetparser',  'allowedContent': True, 'extraAllowedContent': '*(*)' it's not work on empty tag.